# concatenation of channels

Tags: information-theory

Assuming I have 2 channels:

1. BSC => Z
2. Z=> BSC

the first channel is a concatenation of the BSC channel and then the Z channel.
the second channel is a concatenation of the Z channel and then the BSC channel.

Where the Z channel is as defined in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-channel_%28information_theory%29)
and the BSC channel is as defined in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_symmetric_channel)

How can I know which channel has an higher capacity. Is there a difference in the order of the concatenation?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the concatenation of two binary channels is another binary channel, just compute the four transition probabilities

Comment: This is exactly what I did. I just don't know how to compare the channels based on the transition probabilities.

Comment: The capacities are directly comparable in some cases, when one of the channels results as inherently "less noisy" than the other. When that's not the case (here), I don't think there is an esasy way to compare, except computing the capacities explicitly, which is ugly: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/96493/computing-channel-capacities-for-non-symmetric-channels